# Checked checkbox outside the adapter class on listView

Tags: android, listview

In my Activity i have a list view and a check box.I created an adapter and do all stuff about it.In adapter i have 4 checkbox that loaded into list view.

I want to when user check this man checkBox in activity all checkBoxs on adapter is checked so in order to In activity first i find check box and finally i override `setOnCheckedChangeListener` method.

To find out number of view in adapter i am using `TmpAdp.getCount()`.TmpAdp is my instance adapter.
This is a completed code :

```
   chb_allCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                for (int i = 0; i < TmpAdp.getCount(); i++) {
                    View view = Glist.getChildAt(i);
                    CheckBox ch_item = view.findViewWithTag(i);
                    // CheckBox ch_item = view.findViewById(R.id.chb_send_info); // this is not work like findViewWithTag 
                    ch_item.setChecked(true);
                }
                TmpAdp.checkAll(TmpAdp.getCount());
                TmpAdp.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is, when i checked mani check box (chb_allCheck), none of them of check boxs inside adapter is not checked ?
This is a part of adapter class and getView method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Tmpcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.liststyle_saveed, parent, false);

    BtnChangeToInPross = rowView.findViewById(R.id.BtnChangeToInPross);
    TextView txtNosaziCodestr = rowView.findViewById(R.id.NosaziCodestr);
    checkBox = rowView.findViewById(R.id.chb_send_info);
    checkBox.setTag(position);
```

[image]

As you can see when i have clicked on Main check boxs, none of them of check box inside adapter is not checked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tank you of your guys, You have made good suggestions but let me complete my way.

My problem was `TmpAdp.notifyDataSetChanged();`.When i removed this, code work completally.

I have completed my code and works perfectly and it can be an additional way to `Select 
all checkbox`.

```
        chb_allCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < TmpAdp.getCount(); i++) {
                        View view = Glist.getChildAt(i);
                        CheckBox ch_item = view.findViewById(R.id.chb_send_info);
                        ch_item.setChecked(true);
                    }
                    TmpAdp.checkAll(TmpAdp.getCount());
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < TmpAdp.getCount(); i++) {
                        View view = Glist.getChildAt(i);
                        CheckBox ch_item = view.findViewById(R.id.chb_send_info);
                        ch_item.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    TmpAdp.removeAll();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make a Model class. In which you will take boolean `isChecked`.

Now in adapter class you will attach that model boolean to the list item checkbox.

`checkbox.setChecked(model.isChecked());`

When you check your main checkbox. Then just change isChecked boolean in your model list.

```
boolean isChecked = mainCheckBox.isChecked();
for(Model model : adapter.getList()){
  model.setChecked(isChecked);
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here when you change checked status of model and notify your list. Then all your checkBox will be checked automatically, because these are attached to the model checked field.

**It is logic, I did not write full code, you will make Model class, and will attach model by your list item.**

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class and make getter and setter method for check and uncheck Checkbox

Click of Main Checkbox in Activity

```
    chb_allCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean 
                 for (int i = 0; i < yourList.size; i++) {
                      if(checked){
                    yourlist.get(i).setCheckBoxAdapter(true);
                     }
                     else{
                    yourlist.get(i).setCheckBoxAdapter(false);
                    }
}
                   TmpAdp.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
```

in yourAdapterClass

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // Get the data item for this position
       CheckBoxModelClass modelclass= getItem(position);
          if(modelclass.getCheckbox()){
            adapterCheckBox.setChecked(true);
             }
            else{
              adapterCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                   }    


            return convertView;
   }
```